# Flip a matrix up and left

Tags: c, matrix, flip

I'm trying to flip a matrix inside another matrix (using 1D array)

Supposed that I have
a = {1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0}

> 1 2 3 0
>
> 4 5 6 0
>
> 7 8 9 0
>
> 0 0 0 0

I'm trying to flip it up and left to archive:

> 7 8 9 0
>
> 8 5 2 0
>
> 3 6 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 0

What I do is: `array44[SIZEX*a + b + a] = kernel[SIZEY*a + SIZEX - b - 1];` (just for flipping up)

But i always miss 1 element (usually the last one).

How can I improve it?

Comment: Can you define more generally what are you trying to do? I can see where you are aiming at but I'm little bit confused about those zeros.

Comment: I'm trying to flip a matrix inside another matrix (using 1D array)

Comment: Why there isn't `4` in your example after the transformation? Could you please define the operation your trying to do more precisely? Like this: a[0][0] goes to place of a[n-1][n-1] etc.

Comment: Show what you have tried. it's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your code.